# i want to get value from combobox to my search form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a combobox like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="product">Product</option>
    <option value="company">Supplier</option>
</select>
```

I want to get value from combobox to my search form

```
<span class="search_input_box">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="SearchKeyword" value="What are you looking for..." onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='What are you looking for...';" onfocus="if (this.value='What are you looking for...') this.value='';" />
</span>
```

I tried to use `onchange="document.getElementById('hdModule').value=this.value"` in combobox, but it didn't work.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="do" id="hdDo" value="search" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="hdAct" value="lists" />
            <input type="hidden" name="module" id="hdModule" value="product" />sorry i forgot this infomation:

Comment: `onchange="document.getElementById('SearchKeyword').value=this.value`

Comment: but i use class for SearchKeyword :(

Comment: what do you mean? you are using `id` as I can see it from the above.

Comment: oh it's run. but when i chose supplier. it't search by product? why? hel me please :(

Comment: you need to put `onchange="document.getElementById('SearchKeyword').value=this.value' on all your comboboxes

Comment: thanks for your help codehx. it's ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using this code on your `<select>` tag

```
onchange="document.getElementById('hdModule').value=this.value"
```

You're changing the value of `hdModule` instead of the textbox (`SearchKeyword`). You need to change the value of the textbox. Change your code to below

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('SearchKeyword').value=this.value">
    <option value="product">Product</option>
    <option value="company">Supplier</option>
</select>

<span class="search_input_box">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="SearchKeyword" value="What are you looking for..." onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='What are you looking for...';" onfocus="if (this.value='What are you looking for...') this.value='';" />
</span>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kogmyLda/

**EDIT**

If you don't want `Product` or `Supplier` selected at first load, add an empty option as below

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('SearchKeyword').value=this.value">
    <option></option>
    <option value="product">Product</option>
    <option value="company">Supplier</option>
</select>

<span class="search_input_box">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="SearchKeyword" value="What are you looking for..." onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='What are you looking for...';" onfocus="if (this.value='What are you looking for...') this.value='';" />
</span>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kogmyLda/1/

Comment: thanks you a lot ekad. I do like you said, it's run very good!